# How can I pass string to textView using segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, segue

There is a `tableView` which has a `section` with title "Notes". Originally there is one `row` with `string` "Click here to add notes". After clicking the `cell` it `segues` to a `textView` and add notes. Now there is a new cell with note in the section ("Click here to add notes" is the second row now). When clicking the cell with note and segue to the textView again, I want the textView to show the `note` before editing and I pass the note by segue. But the error shows `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Please help to find out the problem.

My code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {

     case 0-3: break

     case 4:

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toTextView", sender: indexPath)

    default: break          
    }

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

if segue.identifier == "toTextView" {

  let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

        let noteText = detailsInSection[4][indexPath.row] as! String

        let textVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TextViewController

        if noteText == "Click here to add notes" {

            // do nothing

        } else {

         textVC.notesTextView.text = noteText  // Break point is here

        }

      }       
}
```

Comment: The `notesTextView` is nil, because the view in `textVC` has not been loaded at this point.  Change your code to add a `noteText` property, set that value in `prepareForSegue`, and then in `viewDidLoad` of the TextViewController, set `notesTextView.text = noteText`.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot and it works well now. Now I understand the reason is that in prepare ForSegue the textView has not been loaded yet. If you like, you can put as an answer and I can accept it. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Many thanks; I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, the `notesTextView` is nil, because the view in `textVC` has not been loaded at this point. Change your code to add a `noteText` property to `TextViewController`, set that value in `prepareForSegue`, and then in `viewDidLoad` of the `TextViewController`, set `notesTextView.text = noteText`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to manipulate another view controller's views. That violates the principle of encapsulation, an important idea in Object Oriented design.

You should treat another view controller's views as private.

@pbasdf explained why it fails in this case (the other view controller's views haven't yet been loaded when `prepareForSegue` is called and are nil).

The clean fix is to add a string property to the destination view controller and set that property.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I have deep understanding about views in a viewController. I cannot manipulate views in other viewControllers.